# Do I need to update my NEMA 10-50 receptacle with no neutral for NEC 2017 code compliant?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I have a lengthy 6/2 run with no neutral and two hots. The oven appliance is configured in 3-wire with the grounding strap connected on the appliance. I have to extend this run by 4 feet via splicing, thus I believe I am held to the new NEC standard (not sure on this though). Since 1996, my oven manual states that new runs must have a 4-wire run (2 hots, a neutral, and a ground). My current wiring is simply using the bare ground as a neutral and I'm not too fond of having some of the 120V return current being run on bare aluminum. Do I have to pull new 6/3 wire? Would a 50 Amp 2-Pole GFCI Circuit Breaker be safe to install on this to protect if I kept the existing wiring?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note - Aluminum wire or cable is fine when you replace this - aluminum heavy feeders were never the problem with aluminum wiring, and the price differential is absurdly in favor of aluminum over copper for a long run of this amperage, even though the wire size has to be larger.

Comment: Can you get a retrofit grounding wire from somewhere on your grounding electrode system or a metal conduit somewhere to the new receptacle location?

Comment: I don't think that will pass, since the neutral would still be on the bare braid of the SE wire.

Comment: Is there enough space for a small "spa panel" sized subpanel somewhere on a nearby wall without compromising its clear working space?

Comment: Yeah, aluminum is the wrong thing to be afraid of, it can be handled.  You should fear the several ordinary wire failures that can cause the chassis of your oven to be energized and kill you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you chose to extend it 4 feet, you chose to **need to replace the whole thing.** Grandfathering dies when you remodel - you can't extend a grandfathered circuit and say "well, it's grandfathered," even though the new work is clearly the grandchild.

The good part is, it will be safer. There's a reason it was banned for everything except the "special interest appliance exception" long before 1996 and finally banned outright for new work. It doesn't kill a lot of people, but it kills people. Run new cable, or new conduit and wires all the way. Two Hots, Neutral, and Ground (or use metal conduit for the ground part.)

EMT Conduit is not all that daunting and may actually save some money over cable.

Your new receptacle will be a NEMA 14-50R, and your new Line cord will be a 4-wire NEMA 14-50P, and you will be removing the bonding strap in your oven per your oven's manual so that the new cord's ground wire is the grounding means, and the new cord's neutral wire is the neutral. Drop your old cord off at the scrapyard...

Comment: +1 for "It doesn't kill a lot of people, but it kills people." This is an opportunity to correct a potentially lethal flaw in your wiring, just do it.

Answer (score 6):

Your current run is "SE cable" aka *Service Entrance* cable. The bare wire is **neutral**.  (Service entrances are the wiring from weatherhead to main breaker, where "ground" does not exist yet). It was allowed until 1966 (before we landed on the moon) for most wiring and until 1996 for ranges and dryers (for some reason???)

The existing cable is #6 aluminum, which *in SE cable* is allowed 50 amps.

You have apprehensions about aluminum; this comes from problems which occurred in the 1970s with *small branch circuits* (15-20A).  But it was only ever a problem for small circuits, not larger wires. And if you examine the fiasco more closely, you'll find it was a) faulty *receptacles* not properly designed for aluminum wire (corrected in the CO-ALR receptacle spec; next time you're in a home store take a look at one of those).  And b) as we only learned last decade, screw torque matters on *all* connections, and in the 70s nobody was using torque screwdrivers on the small stuff. (mandatory as of NEC 2017).

A much greater threat to your safety is the range being ungrounded. That wire is *neutral*. Because of the "hack" they approved in 1966 to ground the chassis *to neutral*, that actually makes these installations *dangerous*.  Neutral is occasionally energized at 120V (that's why it gets insulation in cables other than SE)... and now, your range chassis is energized too.  Touch it wrong and you die.  The "ground to neutral" compromise was a bad idea.

Since you must extend the circuit, there is nothing here of value you can use.  You must start from scratch with 4-wire (/3+ground) cable, or conduit. (EMT metal conduit carries ground on the metal conduit).

Presuming a large socket rated 75C thermal and CU-AL*, Your wire choices are:

- #8 NM or UF: 40A
- #8 any other kind of copper wire: 50A
- #8 aluminum: 35A
- #6 NM or UF: 55A
- #6 aluminum: 50A

On 40A and larger circuits, NM and UF cables are at a disadvantage because of the poor thermal performance of their insulation.

* Large sockets did not have "the problem", and so do not need the CO-ALR "revised" certification.

Comment: > Neutral is occasionally energized at 120V

What causes that?

Comment: @rsaxvc Ordinary wire breaks.  Code designs systems to remain safe despite simple failures, because those can't be prevented.

Comment: Ah, like if neutral line breaks, and is bonded to the range chassis, but hot is still connected, then the chassis could easily become hot?

Comment: @rsaxvc Yes, in that case it's guaranteed to, the moment a 120V load comes on e.g. clock or oven light.  Single point of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to extend it?  Or can the new appliance cord be made to reach?  You are only compelled to upgrade it if you extend or alter it.

Comment: Valid point! However, the upgrade is a _safety_ upgrade and should be done. +1 from me.

Comment: It has to be re-routed entirely for placement. But I'm unsure of plug to upgrade to as I see newer types that look different from the one currently being used.

Comment: @User3219 you need to use 4-prong NEMA 14-50, it is the only choice you have.